# GetAsyncKeyState Multiple characters

Tags: c#, winapi

I have problem with GetAsyncKeyState.

```
public static void GetKey()
{
    string keyBuffer = "";

    foreach (System.Int32 i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
        if (Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i) != "LButton")
        {
            int x = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
            if ((x == 1) || (x == -32767) || (x == -32768))
            {
                keyBuffer += Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i) + " ";
                Object ki = Enum.ToObject(typeof(Keys), i);

                if (keyBuffer == "LButton")
                {
                }
                if (keyBuffer == "RButton")
                {
                }
                if (keyBuffer == "LShiftKey")
                {
                }
                if (keyBuffer == "RShiftKey")
                {
                }
                if (keyBuffer == "RMouse")
                {
                }
                if (keyBuffer == "LMouse")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ki);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i'm getting multiple key when i change code to:

```
if ((x == 1) || (x == -32767))
```

i'm getting only one pressed but i'm not getting keys from excel.

Comment: This is the wrong way to read input. It will not handle shift states, the ctrl key, IME composition, etc. Can you describe what kind of program you are writing? Different frameworks offer different ways of receiving input.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your code, I see a couple of problems.

`GetAsyncKeyState` returns a signed 16 bit `short`. If you've not defined it that way you should change you definition. I say that because I note that you use `int` to hold the return value and wonder whether or not you declared the function correctly.

The other problem that I see with your code is that you test for the key being down incorrectly. Test if the return value is negative to check if the key is down:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(...) < 0)
{
    // key is down
}
```

Beyond that, I expect that you are mistaken in using `GetAsyncKeyState`. Judging from your comments, you are trying to read text input, and `GetAsyncKeyState` is the wrong function for that.

Comment: Well, this not solving the problem multiple keys

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);

Comment: It should be short rather than int on the return value. Not sure why you opted for `Int32` on the `vKey` parameter. May as well use `int` there. And `vKey` is a rather better name than `i`. That said, the declaration at pinvoke.net looks sound to me: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate

Comment: "the problem multiple keys" doesn't mean anything to me. Sorry. I'm just telling you how to detect whether or not a key is down. If you could explain what is meant by "the problem multiple keys" then I might be able to offer more.

Comment: Check this code when you writing for example word "test" in output you get somethig like that wwwoorrrd when i change the code to this: if ((x == 1) || (x == -32767)) i get single chars but i dont get chars from excel

Comment: What is `x == 1` all about. Did you read my answer? Most of your comments make no sense at all. What is `wwwoorrrd`. You didn't post a complete program. I just picked apart the mistakes that were visible in the code that you did post.